# Run Python Scripts from know folder from anywhere in linux

Tags: python, linux

I need to run python scripts from anywhere on my Linux pc.

I have a folder name Tools that hold 100 Scripts and I wonder if there is any way to just write the name of the script in the terminal without having to move to the specific folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add that folder to your `$PATH` variable:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Tools
```

If you place this statement in a file that's executed when you open a shell (e.g., `.bashrc` if you use bash), you won't need to manually run it again.

Comment: Note that if $PATH is empty, this adds `.` to it, too (as an empty string is interpreted as ., at least in bash).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/path/to/Tools`?

Comment: @DanielWalker it should be the full path to that folder. OP mentioned its called `Tools`, so I just assumed that's the entire thing. But if it's somewhere else (e.g., `/home/haymovich/Tools`) the correct full path should of course be used.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create alias: `$ alias shortName="your custom command here"`

https://www.tecmint.com/create-alias-in-linux/